# How to fix crash : ExoPlayer cast extension on Android 9

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-glide, exoplayer, mediarouter

I have a crash in production since I've have release the ability to cast HLS video from my app to a Chromecast using the ExoPlayer Cast Extension. 
It happens 100% on Android 9 and on a variety of devices (Xiaomi Redmi K20, Samsung 
Galaxy S9, ZenFone Max Pro M2 etc...)

Here is my ExoPlayer cast extension implementation :

```
private fun initCast() {
    mediaRouteButton = view?.findViewById(R.id.media_route_button)

    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(activity?.applicationContext, mediaRouteButton)
    val castContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance()
}

private fun prepareCast(title: String) {
    CastContext.getSharedInstance()?.let {
        castPlayer = CastPlayer(it)
    }

    val movieMetadata = MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE)
    movieMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title)
    videoThumbnail?.let {
        movieMetadata.addImage(WebImage(Uri.parse(it)))
    }
    val mediaInfo = MediaInfo.Builder(videoUrl)
        .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
        .setContentType(MimeTypes.VIDEO_UNKNOWN)
        .setMetadata(movieMetadata).build()

    val mediaItems = arrayOf(MediaQueueItem.Builder(mediaInfo).build())

    castPlayer?.setSessionAvailabilityListener(object : SessionAvailabilityListener {
        override fun onCastSessionAvailable() {
            castPlayer?.loadItems(mediaItems, 0, playerViewModel.getVideoPosition(), Player.REPEAT_MODE_OFF)
            playerViewModel.pauseVideo()
        }

        override fun onCastSessionUnavailable() {
            castPlayer?.currentPosition?.let {
            playerViewModel.setVideoPosition(it)
            playerViewModel.playVideo()
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the stacktrace :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'boolean kj1.a' on a null object reference
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzka.zzhx(zzka.java:38)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzmd.zza(zzmd.java:3)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzms.zze(zzms.java:2518)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzlf$zza.zziw(zzlf.java:20)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzlf$zza.zziy(zzlf.java:41)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzlf$zza.zzix(zzlf.java:23)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzlf$zza.zziz(zzlf.java:42)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzbc.zza(zzbc.java:1)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzba.onSessionStarting(zzba.java:49)
   at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.zzag.zza(zzag.java:10)
   at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.zzz.dispatchTransaction(zzz.java:13)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zza.onTransact(zza.java:13)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
   at androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$MediaSessionRecord$1$2.b(MediaRouter.java:14)
   at androidx.mediarouter.media.RegisteredMediaRouteProvider$Connection$1.a(RegisteredMediaRouteProvider.java:39)
   at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifFrameLoader.b(GifFrameLoader.java:50)
   at com.bumptech.glide.manager.TargetTracker.a(TargetTracker.java:42)
   at androidx.media.AudioAttributesImpl.c(AudioAttributesImpl.java:21)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.a(FragmentState.java:11)
   at androidx.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.onTransact(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:5)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzb.zzb(zzb.java:21)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzaf.zzd(zzaf.java:21)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.cast.zzaq.onRouteSelected(zzaq.java:4)
   at androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$CallbackHandler.invokeCallback(MediaRouter.java:3218)
   at androidx.mediarouter.media.MediaRouter$GlobalMediaRouter$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(MediaRouter.java:3168)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6745)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have open an issue in the ExoPlayer github and in Glide github without luck.

Do anybody have an idea of the cause of this crash ?